# UIAlert with a table view inserted?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have been trying for the last few hours to get a UIAlert with a grouped table in it to work. I have finaly got it nearly perfect but i am unable to get the didSelectRow method to be called. I have been following [This Tutorial](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=253622). He

"If you opt to go another route with the table delegation, you still have a little work left to do. The other option is to set the alertView itself as the table’s delegate object. You can then intercept the table’s -didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method and pass that method onto the alertview’s delegate. You will, of course, have to create another protocol for your alertview, maybe , or something similar."

Im not sure how you do this. Also, what would be the best thing to make the delegate (the alert or the class creating the alert)

So my main question is how can i gain access to the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method for the UIAlert table view?

Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling -didSelectRowAtIndexPath: ? Is it in your UITableAlert.m file? This is where the delegate is declared in the tutorial. I haven't read through the whole thing, but basically if you want to implement that method and have it called, you have to declare the  protocol in a header, and assign whatever class that is as tableView.delegate = self in the implementation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Strangley, this is the only place i didnt try `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` It works fine there. Thankyou.